# Generate 2 unique arrays from larger array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `array1` which has a shape `(100, 256, 256)` and I am trying to generate 2 new arrays from the data.

The arrays should have unique values in both.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't populate the 2 arrays with unique values

```
train_data = np.random.choice(array1.shape[0], 70)
test_data = np.random.choice(array1.shape[0], 30)
```

Any suggestions how to go about it?

Comment: Start with a 100 unique random values, and use the first 70 for one, and the rest for the other.  `choice` with `replace=False` or `shuffle` can create those values.

Comment: You have identified the two needed steps (1) generate 100 unique values; (2) Split the list into 70 and 30 values each.  Why did you not write that code?  If you don't know how to do one of the steps, either is a trivial browser search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your problem you can use `np.random.shuffle` as mentioned in the comments like that:

```
a = np.arange(100) #all indices from 0 to 99
np.random.shuffle(a) # shuffle the indices to make it random
train_indices = a[:70]
test_indices = a[70:]

train_data = array1[train_indices]
test_data = array1[test_indices]
```